# C problems list of structures

Tags: c, list, struct

I have the following structs

```
struct jucator{
    char nume[100];
    int *salariu;
    struct jucator *urm;
};

struct echipa{
    char nume[100];
    struct jucator *jc;
    struct echipa *urm;
};

struct echipa *ech;

void adaugajuc(char nume[100],char echipa[100],int salariu)
{
    struct echipa *e=ech;
    while(e)
    {
        if(strcmp(e->nume,echipa)==0) break;
        e=e->urm;
    }
    if(e->jc==NULL)
    {
        e->jc=(struct jucator *)malloc(sizeof(struct jucator *));

        *(e->jc->salariu)=salariu;
        e->jc->urm=NULL;
        strcpy(e->jc->nume,nume);
    }
    else{

        struct jucator *jc=e->jc;

        while(jc->urm&&jc->urm->salariu>salariu) jc=jc->urm;

        if(jc==e->jc&&jc->salariu<salariu)
        {
            struct jucator *nod=(struct jucator *)malloc(sizeof(struct jucator *));

            *(nod->salariu)=salariu;
            nod->urm=jc;
            strcpy(nod->nume,nume);
            e->jc=nod;
        }
        else{

            if(jc!=e->jc&&!jc->urm&&jc->salariu>salariu)
            {
                struct jucator *nod=(struct jucator *)malloc(sizeof(struct jucator *));

                *(nod->salariu)=salariu;
                nod->urm=NULL;
                strcpy(nod->nume,nume);
                jc->urm=nod;
            }
            else{

                struct jucator *nod=(struct jucator *)malloc(sizeof(struct jucator *));

                *(nod->salariu)=salariu;
                nod->urm=jc->urm;
                jc->urm=nod;
                strcpy(nod->nume,nume);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I add elements in the function.The problem is that, if i don't put `*salariu` in the first structure and put only `salariu` there will be elements with a strange value in the `salariu`. 

My question is why?

I specify that each variable is global .

I arrange them based on `salariu` descending.

Please put an explanation too, that why it works like this and without pointer i get strange value(not always).

Comment: i said it was global

Comment: Now you added it uninitialized. Which is a serious problem is in this code, and a likely cause of the bug. But I suppose *that* is is not reflective of your actual code either, is it!?

Comment: To improve your question, consider this: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

`salariu` is a pointer to `int`:

```
struct jucator{
    char nume[100];
    int *salariu;
    struct jucator *urm;
};
```

But you are assigning a plain `int` without dereferencing (and without space for store the value) in:

```
void adaugajuc(char nume[100],char echipa[100],int salariu)
{
struct echipa *e=ech;
while(e)
{
    if(strcmp(e->nume,echipa)==0) break;
    e=e->urm;
}
if(e->jc==NULL)
{
    e->jc=(struct jucator *)malloc(sizeof(struct jucator *));
    e->jc->salariu=salariu; /*HERE */
```

And here:

```
demo.c:42:36: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
     while(jc->urm&&jc->urm->salariu>salariu) jc=jc->urm;
                                    ^
demo.c:44:30: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
     if(jc==e->jc&&jc->salariu<salariu)
                              ^
demo.c:48:21: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
         nod->salariu=salariu;
                     ^
demo.c:55:44: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
         if(jc!=e->jc&&!jc->urm&&jc->salariu>salariu)
```

You can fix this dereferencing the pointer:

```
e->jc->salariu = malloc(sizeof(int)); /* Reseve space for the int */
*(e->jc->salariu)=salariu;
```

Or better yet, use a plain `int` in the `struct`:

```
struct jucator{
    char nume[100];
    int salariu;
    struct jucator *urm;
};
```

Comment: but if i do like this it works. if i delete pointer from salariu it won't work. why?

Comment: but why it works like this and without pointer don't work? that is my question

Comment: Because `salariu` is expecting a pointer, when you assign an `int` to it you are basically saying: the **address** of `object->salariu` is `x`, when you want to say the **value** of  `object->salariu` is `x`, conclusion: a pointer wants an address, not a value, you have two choice, use a plain `int` as member in your `struct`, or reserve space for the pointer and dereference it, I prefer the first method.

Comment: i mean in the structure.If i dont't use at all pointers at salariu(neither is structure nor in the function) when i display the values some are strange . why?

Comment: lets say i don't have pointer in struct jucator. i use it like int salariu. After i go through the function and after that i display the values in main i see that sometimes salariu values are strange.Why?

Comment: It doesn't work with plain int. It gives me strange values.That is what i say to you but you don't want to listen.Why this happens??????

Comment: Because those values are addresses (memory addresses), consider `int x = 15` vs `int *p = 15`, they are not the same, the first one receives a value of 15, the second one is a pointer, you are telling that `p` is a reference to the address 0x15, the address 0x15 contains a value (garbage for you as it is a random address), thats what you are getting: garbage, do you understand now?

Comment: i get garbage if i use int x .I get good values if i use int *p

Comment: Again, you can not assign a plain `int` (the value) to a pointer without space and without dereferencing, a pointer wants an address, you can: 1) use a plain `int`  as member in your `struct` 2) Use a pointer but reserve space for it, then dereference the pointer and assign a value. Obviously you prefer the first method.

Comment: i tried to use all without pointers. I used only pointers to structure but beside it i didn't use pointers. i assigned plain int to plain int (i used plain int in structure) and plain int in function.No pointer. And all goes down to strange numbers.Can you understand that i don't use pointers beside the pointer to structure?

Comment: This could be due to another problem, but we don't have a crystal ball and we can not tell you whats wrong without seeing the full (compilable) code :)